# How to make a bot respond/react to an incoming webhook message in slack?

Tags: bots, slack

I have a use case where something happens in my firebase database and a incoming webhook sends a message to a private slack channel where my slack bot is invited to.

I could not manage to make my slack bot to take notice and react to those messages.

Is there a specific event or authorization scope that I should include in my bot's configuration?

Thanks,

Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Slack does not allow bots to respond to bots. A possible solution is to have your bot listen for a given word (message.channels) using the slack [events api](https://api.slack.com/events-api). You will also have to send `as_user: true` as part of you incoming webhook json. [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) has a tester function that might help sort through the trial and error testing that you will have to do.  You will also be able to see the bot_id and other useful information in the response.